# Getting user information from Etc isn't adding the information to the email

Tags: ruby

I'm writing an email script and need information added to an email regarding the users name this is probably something extremely simple that I'm just over looking (I'm going to have to leave some information out due to security):

```
def get_user
  user = Etc.getlogin
  @esd_user = user.split('_').first.capitalize + ' ' + user.split('_').last[0].upcase
end

def pend
  #-< Pending emails >-#

  email = <<-_END_ 
V/R,
#{@esd_user}
DOL IT ESD

  _END_
  #copy(email)
end
```

At the `@esd_user` part it isn't adding the user information correctly examples:

```
irb(main):004:0> def get_user
irb(main):005:1>   user = Etc.getlogin
@esd_user = user.split('_').first.capitalize + ' ' + user.split('_').last[0].upcase
irb(main):007:1> end
=> :get_user
irb(main):008:0> def email
irb(main):009:1> <<-_END_
irb(main):010:1" V/R,
irb(main):011:1" #{puts @esd_user}
irb(main):012:1" DOL IT ESD
irb(main):013:1" _END_
irb(main):014:1> end
=> :email
irb(main):015:0> email

=> "V/R,\n\nDOL IT ESD\n"
irb(main):016:0>
```

As you can see it's not adding the user to the information.. I don't understand why?

Comment: You defined `get_user`, but it looks like you forgot to call it.

Comment: @Jordan But I also defined an instance variable `@esd_user` which should be accessible throughout the program shouldn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that you never call `get_user`, so no value is assigned to `@esd_user` and its value is `nil`. Your second problem is on the fourth line here::

```
def email
<<-_END_
V/R,
#{puts @esd_user}
DOL IT ESD
_END_
end
```

`puts` prints its arguments to `$stdout` and returns `nil`. You want to interpolate the value of `@esd_user` into the string on that line. You don't want to print anything on that line. Get rid of `puts`:

```
def email
  <<-_END_
V/R,
#{@esd_user}
DOL IT ESD
_END_
end

@esd_user = "foobar"
puts email
# -> V/R
#    foobar
#    DOL IT ESD
```